# Powerpoint - Save group as image via VBA

Tags: vba, image, export, powerpoint

I would like to save a group as a png-Image.

I am able to export an image as a complete slide, but I cannot figure out how to export only a particular group.

This works for a slide:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    neuerText = TextBox1.Value
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Export "C:\bla\" & neuerText & ".png", "PNG"
End Sub
```

But how to select only a group? E.g.

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Group 1").Export "C:\bla\" & neuerText & ".png", "PNG"
```

Ideally, the Image would have a transparent background.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`ShapeRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shaperange) object should work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    neuerText = TextBox1.Value

    Dim myGroup As ShapeRange
    Set myGroup = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Range("Group 1")
    myGroup.Export "C:\bla\" & neuerText & ".png", ppShapeFormatPNG
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Now I get this:

Laufzeitfehler '-2147188160 (80048240)':
Shape (uknown member): Invalid request. To select a shape, its view must be active.